# ultra-slow tablelayout performance

Tags: android, performance, tablelayout

I'm experiencing terrible TableLayout performance. I've read some posts here talking about the same ...

[Android dynamically created table - bad performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9813427/android-dynamically-created-table-bad-performance)

I use a tablelayout inside an already complex layout. I'm already using many views and of course the more views I use, the less the performance, this is obvious, but I wonder how is it possible that the performance is so bad compared to the rest of widgets.

In my case, a tablelayout with let's say 5*5 textviews (only plain textviews in the rows) causes the system to freeze for even more than 1.5 seconds sometimes just by updating a TextView . I am not talking about rendering the whole table, but just updating one textview inside the tablelayout.

I suspected of setColumnsStretchable(), but even setting it to never stretch, the performance is the same.

```
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    final TextView target=(TextView)seekBar.getTag();
    target.setText(""+progress);
}
```

This is the code I use to update a cell. As you see, it's part of a SeekBar listener. I don't even have to findView() or anything, as I store the target textview as the seekbar's tag.

So, moving the seekbar causes jumps: It takes more than one second!! to do the setText() alone. If I update any other textview which is not inside the table, the update is immediate, as expected.

If my table is 10*10, well, it takes like 3 seconds!

Is in your experience TableLayout a no-no or I might be doing something wrong? Maybe some magic values for the rows or cells layoutparams?

Thanks in advance.