# How to add elements after a ListView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Following is my XML of my view. (I only added the structure). The problem is when I have few elements in the list view (dynamically generated), the output will show everything up to last buttons. But once the view grow passing the screen size elements after the listview do not show. But all the elements in the list view appear. How to fix it from changing this XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableRow >
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
<ListView 
    android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableRow >
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
<Button 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
<Button 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: check out [this duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383847/android-layout-with-listview-and-buttons)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ListView` are hungry for height. The worst case of presenting `ListView` is to give it height of `wrap_content`.

As your Items in `ListView` grow bigger, `ListView` increases its height to wrap its content, so as a result it pushes other `View`s out of the screen.

I'll suggest you to give it height of `fill_parent` and play around with `layout_weight` params.

For further reference, I'll recommend you to read [this article](http://blog.maxaller.name/2010/05/attaching-a-sticky-headerfooter-to-an-android-listview/) about using `RelativeLayout` to adjust `ListView` with other `View` and `ViewGroup`.