# Android Layout with ListView overlaps Buttons

Tags: android, listview, layout

I can't seem to find a way to make a layout that contains a ListView that show the entire list of my contacts (its a long list), with 2 buttons one next to the other below the list.

its freaking me out, nothing i do seems to work. i searched some related quiestions and found this one: [Android Layout with ListView and Buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383847/android-layout-with-listview-and-buttons) 
but none of the alternative solutions over there is working for me.

when i look at the graphical presntation (of eclipse) it looks fine, but when i run it on my device i can only see the list of contacts. the listView overlaps the buttons.

I am using a simpleList that render on another layout that represent a row. i'm starting to suspect something i do programtically ruins it, because i ran over my java code and found no mention of the activity_contact_list that i was talking about. only connection to the row layout.

so i got this activity_contact_list.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/contact_list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/action_cancel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Cancle" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/action_add"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Add" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is after many tries such as: using RelativeLayout instead of the LinearLayout, puting the ListView's code below the LinearLayout of the buttons, and many more..

and here is the code of the activity: ContactList.java:

```
public class ContactList extends ListActivity{

//some global variables for late use.
public Model model;                         
SimpleAdapter adapter;
List<Map<String, String>> data;             /* data is a list of Map */
String[] from = {"name","phone"};           /* names of the columns */     //TODO - add date!
int[] to = {R.id.name, R.id.number};    
List<Contact> contacts;                     /* list of contacts */


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //  setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_list);


    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    model = Model.getInstance(this);

    data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>(); 
    contacts = fillContactsList();

    fill_data();
    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.contact_list_row, from, to);
    setListAdapter(adapter);    


}
```

i commented the `setContentView` line cause it doesnt compile otherway...

As is said. the list works perfactly. but it overlaps the buttons at the bottom of the activity. any idea? i'm sure its something silly i'm missing..

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use Relative Layout ?

Change Linear Layout to Relative Layout that's all.

As Linear Layout Doesn't support align parent..

**Edited**

set List Height to mach parent.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/contact_list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_below="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/action_cancel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Cancle" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/action_add"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Add" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hmmm... as i said, i tried that already- doesnt work neither :(
perhaps is it something to do with the fact that nowhere in the java code i attach `activity_contact_list`? i only give the `contact_list_row` to the adapter. so how will it know that i want buttons at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

How long is your ListView. Maybe it is longer than your screen and is the LinearLayout with buttons shown outside your screen.

What happens when you rearrange with the buttons above the ListView.

EDIT:
I think you have to set a Max-size in your ListView. Maybe you can try something like this in your java-code, but I don't know if it is scrollable then...

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView):
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) listView .getLayoutParams();
params.height = 200;    // or something bigger / smaller
listView .setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: its quite long... 491 items. defently longer then my screen - but i want to make the buttons stay at the buttom of the screen no matter what, and the list to be scrolled about it... same as the picture the guy in the post i attched had put.